# Dynamically adding a form to a Django formset with Javascript

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, django-forms

I want to automatically add new forms to a Django formset using Javascript, so that when the user clicks an "add" button it runs JavaScript that adds a new form to the page.

Comment: ref http://django-forms-builder.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

See the code i used,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e){
$(".add-more a").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var id_groupmembers_set = $('#id_groupmembers_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
$(".personal-info-grp ul.user-name").append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, id_groupmembers_set));
 $('#id_groupmembers_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(id_groupmembers_set) + 1);
});

$(".signin-form a.cross-btn").live("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
});
</script>
```

You can use your form id and all in the script.

The example form would be like this

```
<div id="empty_form" style="display:none">
<li>
<div class="signin-form clearfix">
<div class="clearfix">
    <label><span>{% trans 'Name' %}<b>*</b></span>:</label>
    {{ members_form.empty_form.first_name }}{{ members_form.empty_form.name.errors.as_text }}
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
    <label><span>{% trans 'Age' %}<b>*</b></span>:</label>
    {{members_form.empty_form.age}}{{members_form.empty_form.age.errors.as_text}}
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
    <label><span>{% trans 'Gender' %}<b>*</b></span>:</label>
    {{members_form.empty_form.gender}}{{members_form.empty_form.gender.errors.as_text}}
</div>
<a href="#" class="cross-btn"><img src="/static/assets/images/cross-btn.png" alt="" />      </a>
</div>
</li>
</div>
```

Make use of it ;)